# SVG - Circle marker not the same size in all browsers (IE11)

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I tried adding a small circle marker at the end of the `<path>` element but noticed its size is different in IE11, but Chrome, Firefox, Edge have the "correct" size. Example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PQOVYK) (Updated in Edit below)

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path
      stroke="#ffff00"
      fill-opacity="0"
      marker-start="url(#marker)"
      stroke-width="4"
      d="M 50 98 A 48 48 0 0 0 50 2"
    />

   <marker id="marker" refX="5" refY="5" markerWidth="100" markerHeight="100">
     <circle class="marker" fill="#ff0000" cx="5" cy="5" r="1.5" />
   </marker>
</svg>
```

I have also noticed that the fill is not being applied - images show the comparison between Chrome (left) and IE11 (right):

[image: Code rendered in Chrome]
[image: Code rendered in IE11]

Anyone knows the reason for this?

EDIT: I have updated the codepen with the `stroke` and `stroke-width` attribute as per @vals suggestion: [Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/jdomajnko/pen/aqVxza)

```
stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="0"
```

Comment: What you are seeing in IE is a stroke, not a fill

Comment: @vals Ah, I see, if I add the `stroke` attribute the color works. Still don't know why the size is not correct though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, turns out that all you need is to set stroke-width="0", that seems to be default in other browsers, to IE

```css
.svg-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <path
          stroke="#ffff00"
          fill-opacity="0"
          marker-start="url(#marker)"
          stroke-width="4"
          d="M 50 98 A 48 48 0 0 0 50 2"
      />

    <marker id="marker" refX="5" refY="5" markerWidth="100" markerHeight="100">
      <circle class="marker" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="0" fill="#ff0000" cx="5" cy="5" r="1.5" />
    </marker>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy that it helped you !